# I would like a more efficient way to remove characters from nodes in a string of XML

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net, string

I've writen a function that cleans out an XML string. The string of XML eventually gets read into a dataset

```
favoriteDataSet.ReadXml(New System.IO.StringReader(sCleanedXML))
```

so this function is setup to clean the offending characters without removing them if they are actually valid xml characters.

So if I sent in

```
<Some&Text/ToClean> blah blah blah </Some&Text/ToClean>
```

I would get back

```
<Some_Text_ToClean> blah blah blah </Some_Text_ToClean>
```

It works but I'd really like to learn how to implement it more efficiently.

It accepts...

- **sOriginal**  which is a long string of xml with tags 
  like  blah blah blah
- **asBetween**  which is a string of characters to look between to 
  find the offending characters.  The string of characters is pipe delimited.
  (ie. asBetween = "<|>")
- **sRemovalTokens**  which is a string of pipe delimited values to clean out.
  (ie. sRemovalTokens = "&|/|#"

Here is the code...

```
 Private Function CleanXMLTags(sOriginal As String, asBetween As String, sRemovalTokens As String) As String
    Try
        Dim aBookEnds() As String = asBetween.Split("|")
        Dim aRemovalTokens() As String = sRemovalTokens.Split("|")
        Dim iStartIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim iEndIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim sCurToken As String = String.Empty
        Dim sReplaceToken As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To aRemovalTokens.Length - 1
            If aBookEnds.Length = 2 AndAlso Not String.Equals(aRemovalTokens(i).Trim, "", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                iStartIndex = 0
                iEndIndex = 0
                While iStartIndex > -1
                    iStartIndex = sOriginal.IndexOf(aBookEnds(0), iEndIndex)
                    iEndIndex = sOriginal.IndexOf(aBookEnds(1), iEndIndex + 1)
                    If iStartIndex < 0 OrElse iEndIndex < 0 Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                    sCurToken = sOriginal.ToString.Substring(iStartIndex, iEndIndex - iStartIndex + 1)
                    If sCurToken.ToString.StartsWith("</") Then
                        sCurToken = sCurToken.Substring(2)
                    End If
                    If sCurToken.ToString.EndsWith("/>") Then
                        sCurToken = sCurToken.Substring(0, sCurToken.Length - 2)
                    End If
                    If sCurToken.Contains(aRemovalTokens(i)) Then
                        sReplaceToken = sCurToken.Replace(aRemovalTokens(i), "_")
                        sOriginal = sOriginal.Replace(sCurToken, sReplaceToken)
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        Next
        Return sOriginal 'Cleaned
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return sOriginal
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
Private Function GetBetween(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Str1 As String, ByVal Str2 As    String, Optional ByVal Index As Integer = 0) As String

    Return Regex.Split(Regex.Split(Source, Str1)(Index + 1), Str2)(0)

End Function
```

This function returns a string value that is determined by taking the source(your xml file in a compatible form) and locating Str1 and extracts and returns all text between there and Str2.